# Split the String when it contains operation symbols in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I want to split the string when it contains the symbol "+" and "-", how can I do that?

Example:

```
str1 = "2x^3+3x-8";


//Result:
['2x^3', '3x', '8']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex split should work here:

```java
String str1 = "2x^3+3x-8";
String[] parts = str1.split("[+-]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));  // [2x^3, 3x, 8]
```